# 2008 Chrysler Sebring 3.5L 6 Cylinder - Hard Start when Warm

Tags: engine, starting, chrysler, hot-start

I have a 2008 Chrysler Sebring 3.5
L 6 Cylinder engine. It starts right up when cold. If I try to start the vehicle when warm, it seems to take a while to start, approximately 5 seconds of cranking.

Other than this, the vehicle idles and performs well - there is no rough idle or loss of performance. The battery and starter seem strong.

I have cleaned the throttle body and Air Temp Sensor and MAP sensor. If this car has a MAF, I cannot find it or a reference to it's location.  I also used a can of injector cleaner and checked the Air filter.

If it was the fuel pump or filter, I would expect loss of power AND performance or stumbling. I would also expect a hard start when cold. This problem only happens when the engine is warm.

Comment: Does your temperature gage work? Could be faulty engine temp sensor.

Comment: Temp gauge seems fine.